# EF (Entity Framework) 4.3 Migration tool does not work on EF 4.1 DB

Tags: entity-framework, entity-framework-4.1, code-first, entity-framework-4.3, entity-framework-migrations

I want to modify one DB which was developed with EF 4.1 (Code First). I upgraded the project into EF 4.3 and follow this steps:
http://blogs.msdn.com/b/adonet/archive/2012/02/09/ef-4-3-automatic-migrations-walkthrough.aspx

Everything is going well, but when I want to test on current DB (EF 4.1 Code First), Update-Database raise this error:

> Cannot scaffold the next migration because the target database was
>   created with a version of Code First earlier than EF 4.3 and does not
>   contain the migrations history table. To start using migrations
>   against this database, ensure the current model is compatible with the
>   target database and execute the migrations Update process. (In Visual
>   Studio you can use the Update-Database command from Package Manager
>   Console to execute the migrations Update process).

I was wondering how I can migrate an EF 4.1 (Code First) DB? Moreover that DB is live and has data and I cannot drop tables.

Comment: Read error message. Follow directions.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You need to create an empty migration and execute it prior to doing changes to your model. It will create the migration history table for you. After that you can use migrations for new changes. I wrote [walkthrough article](http://www.ladislavmrnka.com/2012/03/ef-4-3-migrations-and-existing-database/) about this topic.

Comment: Hi Ladislav, I followed your instruction, but when I wanted to adding initial migration in Package Manager Console (PM> Add-Migration InitialMigration -IgnoreChanges) it raised this error again: "Cannot scaffold the next migration because the target database was created with a version of Code First earlier than EF 4.3 and does not contain the migrations history table...."

Comment: It worked, the clue is you should do "Add-Migration InitialMigration -IgnoreChanges" before any changes

Comment: That is mentioned in the last paragraph of the article.

Comment: I updated my article to contain information about your issue (linking this question).

Comment: To clarify, Your Model classes MUST CURRENTLY MATCH your database for this answer to work.  If you made changes (like me) and then tried to do a migration for the first time, you'll need to go back and REVERT YOUR MODEL CHANGES before you can enable and use Migrations.

Answer (score 0):

Run "Add-Migration InitialMigration -IgnoreChanges" before doing any changes to the model.. Make the required changes, then run "update-database"