# how does the Table _MigrationHistory under the CODE FIRST in the Entity Framework create?

Tags: entity-framework, code-first, entity-framework-migrations

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [EF (Entity Framework) 4.3 Migration tool does not work on EF 4.1 DB](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9523133/ef-entity-framework-4-3-migration-tool-does-not-work-on-ef-4-1-db)

when use the entity framewrok code first mode to build database,  a table '_MigrationHistory' of system table type will be created. how do I manually create table like that? the code first tutorial show us how to code first to build a new database,not on an exist database, and when I want to use the database migration function of the code first on existing database , I found I failed. and NO table named '_MigrationHistory' created. and I found a solution 'http://thedatafarm.com/blog/data-access/using-ef-migrations-with-an-existing-database/' can resolve my problem, but there is a step need to copy(should be 'create' here) the table '_MigrationHistory' to the existing database which is object of system type, how do I create a table like that?

I WAS POOR IN ENGLISH, MIGHT MY EXPRESS MAKE YOU CONFUSED. HOEP NOT.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't need to create __MigrationHistory manually. You just need to create initial migration. The initial migration will create the table for you. This command will add initial migration called `InitialMigration` and ignore all entities you have in your project:

```
Add-Migration InitialMigration -IgnoreChanges
```

It means that you should run this command when your classes in the application reflect your initial database. All changes which should be handled by migrations must be done after creating the initial migration. [Here](http://www.ladislavmrnka.com/2012/03/ef-4-3-migrations-and-existing-database/) is the whole tutorial.

Comment: I read your post, it's great helpful , thanks.