# EF 4.1 to EF 5.0 Migration (entity.tt files)

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework-4.1, entity-framework-5, texttemplate

I have a project EF in 4.1 that I want to migrate to 5.0. Originally the entity code generation templates included some `Association Fixup` functions including `FixupFrame` and `FixupCluster`. Are these still neccessary in 5.0?

What else should I look out for when migrating?

Comment: Take a look at this question. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9523133/ef-entity-framework-4-3-migration-tool-does-not-work-on-ef-4-1-db